# proxyTable not used with axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-resource

I am using cross-env npm package to run my dev server. I was using vue-resources before, but I read that it is not recommended anymore, so I switched to axios library. Unfortunately now proxyTable that is configured with cross-env is not working. Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: Whats the error you are getting?

Comment: No error, it is just ignoring proxyTable. Requests are not overwritten and it is not locating the proxyTable.target

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue. Now fixed with adding pathRewrite to proxyTable config, like

```
{
  ......,
  pathRewrite:{
    '^/api':""
  }
}
```

I don't know why I need this, but it works for me.

Comment: It simply takes /api out of the final target url. So for example a GET request to http://example.com/api/users/1 proxies to http://example.com/users/1